# Absurd audio latency with AudioTrack when display is off

Tags: android, audio, latency

I am playing a stream I got from a UDP socket using AudioTrack inside of a service. It works fine with acceptable latency when screen is on but as soon as screen turns off, the latency increase to somewhere around 5-10 seconds. I've looked through Android documentation and also searched a lot on Google but so far couldn't find the reason for this.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: i can say that audiotrack playback of a wave file on SD card works nicely with switched off screen via a service. i'm afraid i don't have experiences about network streaming.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the wifi not the audio playing itself. Network latency increases while display is off.